# JavaScript nested for loops to display numbers without HTML

Tags: javascript, for-loop, numbers, nested-loops

I need to display a number range between 1 and 30 in the console, but in a specific way. While I've figured out how to get the range using a for loop, I have not figured out how to display the numbers in the console like in the *image shown below* where each * represents a number 1-30. I need numbers 1-30 to be displayed 7 rows across, and 5 rows down, without using HTML tables.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdCzz.png)

My code, to display the number range, is as follows:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{

    var output = " ";
    for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j += 1)
    {
    output +=  "*" + "\t";
    }

console.log(output);

}
```

So far I have tried adding a third nested for loop, but there will be 5 iterations of 1 - 30 displayed 7 times. I have also tried using an array of 1-30, a while loop, an if statement, and have tried adding or multiplying variables with similar results.

I can't help but feel like I am approaching this the wrong way. I am considering using an array and having the inner for loop display each index of the array, but I am not sure if JavaScript has the ability to move to the next index after printing the previous index (1 then 2 then 3, etc) in the way in which I need it to as shown in the image.

Comment: console.log can only show under developer console tab.

Comment: I think you just need to add newline("\n")

Comment: If you want seven across, then your innermost loop needs to go from 1 to 7, or from 0 to 6, but you have it going from 0 to 7, which is eight times. Also, seven across times five down is 35, not 30.

Comment: @torazaburo yes it will result in 35 not 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This code works**

```
var output="";var count = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{

    //output = " ";
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j += 1)
    {
   output +=(count+1)+"\t";count ++;
   }output+="\n";

//document.write(output);

}
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  
29  30  31  32  33  34  35
```

Problem in Question:

> Question States -Number range between 1 and 30 in the console but specified order of
>   matrix is 7*5 which is equal to 35 not 30 which was wrongly mentioned
>   in the questiion.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is eight across, but the OP wants seven across.

Comment: He wants to print out the numbers, not the stars. The stars in his examples are placeholders for actual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by **@torazaburo** the ***OP*** is looking to populate ***numbers*** as opposed to  **[ * ]** . Though **SaiKiranUppu** had a satisfactory answer and should be awarded the upvote, I wanted to offer another solution:

JS:

```
function matrix(r, c) {
  var n = '';
  var x = 1;
  for(var i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      n += x + '\t';
      x++;
    }
    n += '\n';
  }
  console.log(n);
};
matrix(5, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Welcome to SO!

A newline element after every outer loop should do the trick. Something like this.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
      var output = "";
      for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j += 1)
        {
         output +=  "*" + "\t";
        }
      output += "\n";
      console.log(output);
    }
```

**Edit:** Realised OP wanted numbers and not *s. A simple modification to the code makes this unbelievably easy.

```
var output = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
      for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j += 1)
        {
         output +=  i*j + "\t";
        }
      output += "\n";
   }
   console.log(output);
}
```

**Output** - Chrome Developer Tools Screenshot
[image: Chrome Developer Tools Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your input! These solutions have been extremely helpful in bettering my understanding of where I went wrong, what I was overthinking (thus adding to the problem), and how to develop a better solution going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this. I do it only for your..

```
    var lastJ = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

        var output = " ";
        var j = lastJ ;
        var totalLoop = j+4;
        for (j = lastJ; j <= totalLoop; j++) {
            output += j + "\t";
        }

        console.log(output);
        lastJ = j;
    }
```

output is like this
[console output in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uckxJ.png)

If you want calendar like output use this

```
var lastJ = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        var output = " ";
        var j = lastJ ;
        var totalLoop = j+6;
        for (j = lastJ;j <= totalLoop; j++) {
            if(j<32){
              output += j + "\t";
            }else{
                output += 0 + "\t";
            }
        }

        console.log(output);
        lastJ = j;
    }
```

output is like this

```
 1  2   3   4   5   6   7   
 8  9   10  11  12  13  14  
 15 16  17  18  19  20  21  
 22 23  24  25  26  27  28  
 29 30  31  0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i += 10) {
for (var j = i; j < i + 10; j++) {
    document.write(j + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}
document.write("<br>");
}
```